# How to know if ID is expired or not? Then automatically refresh for new GCM ID without change in Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Please, I want clear explanation. I checked on Google, but I am not getting proper solution about it.

- Exception getting GCM certificate expire.

Comment: I have no idea what you are taking about. Do you mean the registration id?

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller, yes i talk about registration Id

Comment: In your `InstanceIDListenerService` you get a callback to `onTokenRefresh()` if the registration id expires. You can then notify your backend about the new one. This is covered in the official GCM documentation and tutorials on developers.google.com. Also quick side not: Google Cloud Messaging has been replaced by Firebase Cloud Messaging. You should really migrate your app if you have the chance. You don't need to change much.